# Associations in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, associations

I have created a user using device authentication. I also have created article view, controller and model where model has fields such as `title`, `body` and `article_id`.  Now I want to implement comments (with the condition that only logged in user can comment on an article). I have created an `is_admin` as a special user that has power create new articles through application.

The User table has all fields that are default generated by device. The Article table has fields like `article_id`, `title`, and `body`. There is still no association between user and article table. The Comment table will have (according to my understanding) `comment_id`, and `comment_body`.

Expected Associations:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
```

I want to make sure that only logged in users can comment on articles, and that `is_admin` user can create new articles.

How can I create association between user, article and comment tables? Do I need to create association for user and comment table?

Comment: Your question is really a very basic "how does Rails work?" question. I would strongly recommend working through a rails tutorial, or documentation such as http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, before bringing questions to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to go through the rails guide and small blog to understand association as @dpassage suggested in comment. Looks you already have work around, so let me consolidate.

As you described, you will have three model:

First: User

```
class User
  has_many :articles  # not dependent => :destroy, may you not want to destroy article on deletion of user
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy 
end
```

Second: Article

```
class Article
    has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Third: Comment

```
class Comment
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :article
end
```